# Hibernate createCriteria() excludes null results

Tags: java, hibernate

```
Criteria cats = sess.createCriteria(Cat.class).add( Restrictions.like("name", "jerry");
Criteria kittens = cats.createCriteria("kittens");
List catList = cats.list();
```

Above, only cats with associated kittens will be included in the results. Cats that meet the 'name=jerry' restriction will *not* be included in the results if their 'kittens' foreign key is null. That seems odd because I did not put any restrictions on 'kittens'. I have two questions: why does this behavior occur? What is the ideal way to avoid this behavior and return the cats regardless if they have kittens (is it createAlias)?

The reason this question comes up is because, using a conditional, I might want to do something like the following:

```
if (someCondition) kittens.add(restriction);
```

Therefore, establishing the 'kitten' criteria ahead of time makes sense from a practical standpoint, although it did not work as I intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With both HQL and Criteria, whenever you specify an implicit join, Hibernate will assume you wanted an INNER JOIN. And INNER JOINs are filtering out nulls.

You need to use a left join instead, from Cat to kittens.

```
criteria.addAlias("kittens","kitten", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN);
```